# Creating ggplot2 x-axis month labels with just first letter of each month

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, label

I know that using `scale_x_date(date_labels="%b"...)` creates tick labels containing the first three letters in each month. Is there any way to just include the first letter of each month? So instead of `"Jan Feb March..."`, the labels would be `"J F M..."`.

Here's an example: The month labels overlap, so I was hoping to be able to change the labels to just the first letter.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)


set.seed(2)
df = data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31p
                                                   "), by="1 day"))
df$value = cumsum(rnorm(nrow(df)))


p = ggplot(df, aes(Date, value)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(df$Date[yday(df$Date)==1]), colour="grey60") +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = year_labels <- rep(c('J','F','M','A','M','J','J','A','S','O','N','D'),5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x="")
p
```

[image]

I tried to change the line `scale_x_date(date_labels="%b", date_breaks="month", expand=c(0,0))` to `scale_x_continuous(labels = year_labels <- rep(c('J','F','M','A','M','J','J','A','S','O','N','D'),5))`

but this produced the below error

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: can you please provide a reproducible example

Comment: your example is not reproducible

Comment: I just skip the line `geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(df$Date[yday(df$Date)==1]), colour="grey60")` which I consider only part of the *decoration* and it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it. Does anyone know of a simpler way to produce the same output?

```
set.seed(2)
df = data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="1 day"))
df$value = cumsum(rnorm(nrow(df)))

year_labels <- rep(c('J','F','M','A','M','J','J','A','S','O','N','D')p,6)


# The plot we'll start with
p = ggplot(df, aes(Date, value)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(df$Date[yday(df$Date)==1]), colour="grey60") +
  geom_line() +
  #  scale_x_continuous(labels = year_labels) +
  scale_x_date("Date",breaks = c(seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"),to=as.Date("2015-12-31"),by="month")),
               labels = year_labels) 
p
```

[image]

Comment: there is a really nice solution for this on this blog: http://www.jasonfabris.com/blog/dteformat/

Answer (score 1):

I think the nicest way is to use `pretty_breaks` from the package `scales`. It in not producing the output you request, but I think is nicer and works smoothly for any length of data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(2)
df = data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2014-12-31p
                                               "), by="1 day"))
df$value = cumsum(rnorm(nrow(df)))

p = ggplot(df) +
   geom_line( aes(Date, value), size=0.1) +
   scale_y_continuous(name= "Title of y [units]")+
   scale_x_date(breaks=pretty_breaks(), date_minor_breaks="1 month") + 
   theme_bw() 
p
```

[image]

[image]

Here I changed the `date_minor_breaks="6 months"`to avoid the excess of *months*
[image]

Nice and simple!!

Comment: Thanks Marco. That isn't really very useful for my current task, but in the future I think I'll refer back to your post. Your plots look nice and I'll have to look into the scales package.